# Transformers on tv signals

Tags: transformer, antenna

Are transformers used in moving the AC signal from the antenna to the TV? I am asking this because the electromagnetic waves must hit the entire antenna for voltage to be produced . Also how some types of antennas convert the sinusiodal wave to square signal?I haven't really understood it yet.

Comment: Why do you think that antennas convert sine waves to square waves?

Comment: I don't think they do just I have seen somewhere it said some types of antenna can convert sine waves to square signals.

Comment: Antennas are linear elements, which means they cannot convert a sinusoid to a square wave.

Answer (score 2):

BALUNS are often used to interface rabbit-ears to the front filters and amplifiers of TVs.

The BALanced-to-UNbalanced transformer likely has wide bandwidth, compared to the antenna.

I've heard simple antennas have about 5% bandwidth (do your own research); 5% will not support either the low_TV nor the hi_TV bands, and certainly will not support the risetimes of a 100 or 200MHz squarewave.

ohhh rabbit-ears? those are independently adjustable halves of a dipole.

Experts would use sheets of aluminum foil, either as reflectors or, capacitively coupled thru the aluminum oxide surface tarnish, as nominally-in-contact element_broadbanding_experiments.

Comment: What is a BALUN and a rabbit ear?

Comment: Not to mention converting a balanced input to a single-ended output. Tough question...

Comment: @McCarter If possible Google those terms and you will find more than you can read in your life time.

Comment: I was right a transformer is used.

Comment: @McCarter: "Rabbit ears" are (were?) set-top TV antennas.